# What is aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership? Which one should I use? What is the difference?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, database-design, asp.net-membership

I'm using default membership class in my website. But I'm a little confused with the complex database design of the ASPNETDB.

Let's say I want to add details about user like name, surname, address etc... Where should I put them aspnet_Membership table or aspnet_Users table and why? I mean I can see that I should put the details on aspnet_Membership. But then again why there is two of them and the bindings on aspnet_Users...

Or lets say I'm adding a messaging into that which table should I key to, for the user details?

I'm confused and I would be appreciated if you can tell me the use of these two tables.

Here is the diagram for the default ASPNETDB which you should probably have:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than modifying the built in ASP.NET membership schema, you can use [ASP.NET profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) to store custom properties about your users. Here's [one tutorial](http://odetocode.com/Articles/440.aspx) on the subject.

You can add the profile tables to your schema using [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (which you're probably already familiar with, given that you have already generated most of the schema). Use the `-R p` switch to get the profile tables/procs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't knew or searched for the usage of profiles before. And great tutorial!. Though I'm still not sure if I use some more tables into the database that are related to Users. Which table should I reference users or membership, or can I also solve it with profiles and how? Thank you!

Comment: In this case, if you need to store more complex properties (like 1 to many relationships), I would create any new tables that you need, and glue things together with a foreign key on the `ApplicationId` and `UserId` fields of the `aspnet_Membership` table.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to connect your custom table to ASP.NET membership, use `UserId` as foreign key from `aspnet_Users` table rather than `aspnet_Membership` table to your custom table. For reference, please note how `aspnet_Profile` or even `aspnet_Membership` is using `UserId` as foreign key from `aspnet_Users` table.

Please see the database diagram here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa478948.asp2prvdr0102l(l=en-us).gif](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa478948.asp2prvdr0102l%28l=en-us%29.gif)

Good luck ...

Answer (score 2):

I would advise not to alter any of the tables provided by the ASP.NET membership schema. To store additional data use the already mentioned ASP.NET profiles option or create a custom one which maybe fits your bill beter.

The reason why there are two tables for storing user data is already answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489809/why-does-asp-net-membership-have-a-users-table-and-a-membership-table). 
Good luck which choosing the right solution.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't saw that question, its definitely the thing i need to put out my curiosity.